# What effects can be expected for a 15-year old girl getting 4-5 hours of sleep per night?

Tags: sleep, mental-health, sleep-cycles, sleep-deprivation, adolescents-teenagers

Say a 15-year old girl on average falls asleep around 3am and wakes up around 7am, over a very long period of time. What short-term and future mental/physical effects can be expected?

Comment: Welcome Joe.  I recommend looking up sleep deprivation in adolescents.  It's a very broad topic and I think too broad to answer adequately in SE format.